# Display the execution plan/statistics for MongoDB

Tags: performance, mongodb, query-optimization

Is there a way for me to see how MongoDB executed a query, i.e. which indexes it used, how many blocks it scanned, how much time that took, and so on?

Similar to what AUTOTRACE would show you in SQL*Plus for Oracle?

Answer (score 5):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain

Comment: new link is :     http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/